# Reading values with different datatypes inside a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, eval

Assume i have a string 
`var str = " 1, 'hello' "`
I'm trying to give a function the above values found in `str` but as integer and string- not as one string-
for example `myFunc(1,'hello')`
how can i achieve that
i tried using `eval(str)`,
but I'm getting `invalid token ,`
How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work with any number of arguments.

```js
function foo(num, str) {
  console.log(num, str);
}

const input = "1, 'hel,lo'";
const args = JSON.parse('[' + input.replace(/'/g, '"') + ']');

foo(...args);
```

Comment: but ill have to pass the arguments manually to the implementation of the function.
isnt there another way to pass the parameters because the string `input` may change thus the parameters should also be changed

Comment: @OsamaAlZahabi You can pass the arguments as `foo(args[0], args[1])` as well. If this doesn't help, can you give some examples?

Comment: @OsamaAlZahabi You can also define the function as `foo(...args)` and it'll receive the arguments as an array.

Comment: i meant that the number of args can change as well thus parameters should be changed too

Answer (score 0):

You've almost got the right idea with `eval(str)` however, that isn't the thing you actually want to evaluate. If you do use `eval(str)`, it is the same as saying `eval(" 1, 'hello' ")`

However, what you really want to do is:
`eval("func(1, 'hello world'))`.

To do this you can do:

`eval(func.name + '(' + str.trim() + ')');`

Here we have:

- `func.name`: The name of the function to call. You can of course hard code this. (ie just write "func(" + ...)
- `str.trim()`: The arguments you want to pass into the given function. Here I also used `.trim()` to remove any additional whitespace around the string.

Take a look at the snippet below. Here I have basically written out the above line of code, however, I have used some intermediate variables to help spell out how exactly this works:

```js
function func(myNum, myStr) {
  console.log(myNum*2, myStr);
}

let str = " 1, 'hello, world'";


// Build the components for the eval:
let fncName = func.name;
let args = str.trim();
let fncStr = fncName + '(' + args + ')';

eval(fncStr);
```

**Alternatively**, if you only wish to pass in two arguments you can use `.split(',')` on your string to split the string based on the comma character `,`.

Using split on `" 1, 'hello' "` will give you an array such as this one `a`:

`let a = [" 1", "'hello'"];`

Then cast your string to an integer and remove the additional quotes around your string by using `.replace(/'/g, '');` (replace all `'` quotes with nothing `''`):

```
let numb = +a[0].trim(); // Get the number (convert it to integer using +)

let str = a[1].trim().replace(/'/g, ''); // get the string remove whitespace and ' around it using trim() and replace()
```

Now you can call your function using these two variables:

`func(numb, str);`

```js
function func(myNum, myStr) {
  console.log('The number times 2 is:', myNum*2, "My string is:", myStr);
}

let arguments = " 1, 'hello' ";
let arr = arguments.split(',');

let numb = +arr[0].trim(); // Argument 1
let str = arr[1].trim().replace(/'/g, ''); // Argument 2

func(numb, str);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! 
but i cant use `split` because the string itself may contain a comma

Comment: @OsamaAlZahabi Ah, I see. I've updated the top half of my answer to use `eval()`as your original question did. This method works for multiple arguments and with commas within the string :)